Ubuntu 24.04 doesn't load GUI and login screen after Upgrade from 23.10
Yesterday I upgraded my Ubuntu from 23.10 to 24.04.
After successful upgrade, I suspended the system and went to sleep.
Today, I noticed that the system stuck at login page.
I rebooted the system and noticed that the boot process moves forward but instead of showing the login page, it shows me the list of started services.
I didn't notice anything wrong in that log.
I switched to tty2 and by running systemctl status gdm noticed that it failed to start. And the result was similar to the screenshot of this question.

In tty2 (Ctrl+Alt+2), I ran the following commands to reinstall a fresh gdm3 package:
sudo apt purge gdm3
sudo apt install gdm3

Right after installation, login screen appeared. I logged in and restarted the system to ensure it continues to work properly.
It fixed my problem.
