Can't boot due to GDM Ubuntu 24.04LTS
I Can't boot due to GDM Ubuntu 24.04 LTS also when I have internet connection I can ping Google.com and Ubuntu.com but I can't install or reinstall or update using apt even with changing DNS I think it is due to my region internet limitations.
This question is not duplicate because my main problem is I can't do it because of my region internet limitations. Actually, internet is useless here without VPN and DNS.

Pls go here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1516754/ubuntu-24-04-doesnt-load-gui-and-login-screen-after-upgrade-from-23-10/1516755?r=SearchResults&s=6%7C0.0000#1516755

This question is similar to: Ubuntu 24.04 doesn't load GUI and login screen after Upgrade from 23.10. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

My main problem is I can't do it because of my region internet limitations, actually internet is useless here without VPN and DNS

pls see this https://askubuntu.com/questions/57339/connect-disconnect-from-vpn-from-the-command-line
